# jsonp no funciona con ionic

Tags: angularjs, ajax, json, ionic, jsonp

Que tal, llevo unos 5 dias intentando hacer funcionar en ionic jsonp y el caso es que con angularjs funciona y con jquery tambien pero cuando utilizo jsonp con ionic no logro hacer que funcione y siempre me devuelve error, aqui os comparto mi codigo

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  // We must whitelist the JSONP endpoint that we are using to show that we trust it
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'http://*/**'
  ]);
}])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
})

.controller("movies",function($scope,$http, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      $scope.items = [];

      var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/llantas/index.php';
      $http.jsonp(url,{name:'texto'}).
      then(function(response) {
          console.log('entra');
        }, function(response) {
          console.log(response['data']+'-'+response['status']);
      });
    });
});
```

index.php

```
<?php
$user     = $_GET['name'];
$arr = array('consulta' => "$user");
$enc = json_encode($arr);
//header('Content-Type: application/json;');
echo($enc);
?>
```

Cuando intento obtener una respuesta con ajax todo funciona perfectamente, tengo como respuesta lo que le envio pero cuando lo intento desde el código que tengo en ionic no funciona y he probado de varias maneras como

**$http({method,url,data:{})**

y sigo obteniento un error el cual es
**undefined-404**

que viene de la siguiente linea
**console.log(response['data']+'-'+response['status']);**

Ya no se me ocurre que puede estar pasando, he visto todas las respuesta de google y de el foro stackoverflow en ingles i en español y no logro solucionar este problemas, otra cosa a decir es que mediante el navegador poniendo la url
**localhost:8080/llantas/index.php?name=texto**
tambien obtengo la respuesta esperada
¿donde está el error?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar de esta manera :

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/llantas/index.php';
  $http.get(url,{name:'texto'}).
  then(function(response) {
      console.log('entra');
    }, function(response) {
      console.log(response['data']+'-'+response['status']);
  });
}
```